# Tiny MCE Image upload endpoint

Tags: image-processing, tinymce, mcimagemanager

I am trying to figure out how I can set my own image upload endpoint in TinyMCE. I can't seem to find it in the documentation and would rather not use MCImageManager because it has way too many features for what I want to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I would suggest is to blow away the advimage button and specify your own upload image button. good for if you are using the jquery plugin.

```
    $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
        // Location of TinyMCE script
        script_url : '../../../js/vendor/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        // General options
        theme : "advanced",
        skin : "bootstrap",
        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "uploadimageCustom, save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "Some User",
            staffid : "991234"
        },

        setup: function (fn) {
            fn.addButton('uploadimageCustom', {
                title : 'Upload Image',
                onclick : function () {
                    // pop open your own upload modal.
                            $(selector).modal('show')
                                                           // modal has fine uploader or other plugin.

                            // after xhr for image uploading is done or on 'complete' event for fineuploader
                            // insert your image html to the textarea with 

                  $('#content').tinymce().execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img src="<your newly uploaded image src>" />');"
                }
            });
        }
```